# Difference between vectors and arrays in Modelica

Tags: arrays, vector, modelica, dymola

I noticed the following line in the transfer function block in the Modelica library (Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.TransferFunction):

```
parameter Real bb[:] = vector([zeros(max(0,na-nb),1);b]);
```

I don't understand what the "vector" function call does, and why it is even necessary. Wouldn't

```
parameter Real bb[:] = [zeros(max(0,na-nb),1);b];
```

lead to the same result?

I found the following explanation in the Modelica Language Specification 3.2, but it doesn't really help:

"vector(A) - Returns a 1-vector, if A is a scalar and otherwise returns a vector containing all the elements of the array, provided there is at most one dimension `size > 1`."

I assume the whole story is based on some difference between arrays and vectors in Modelica. I would be grateful if someone helped me sort it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: A vector is a one-dimensional array.

Imagine we declared something like this:

```
Real x[1,5,1,1];
```

Not there are only 5 elements in this thing and they are all contained in the same dimension.  So what if we wanted to convert this to a simple vector of 5 elements.  We could do this:

```
Real y[5] = { x[1,i,1,1] for i in 1:5 };
```

But that gets tedious.  The alternative is:

```
Real y[5] = vector(x);
```

The compiler looks at this and automatically finds the dimension that has a `size>1` and then pulls all the elements out as a vector.

And just to address one point you brought up, this is not valid:

```
Real z[5] = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Because the left hand side is a vector (one dimensional) and the right hand side is an array.  Normally, if you wanted to use the right hand side, the left hand side would have to be:

```
Real z[1,5] = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

If you want to stuff it into a vector, you need to convert the right hand side from an array to a vector, i.e.,

```
Real z[5] = vector([1,2,3,4,5]);
```

Does that help?